# Android editText.getText()

Tags: android, tostring, gettext, tone-generator

What is wrong with the code:

```
String maintext = (String) main_text.getText().toString();

if(maintext =="10") {           
    ToneGenerator toneG = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100);
    toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200);
}
```

The code is working without if statement but with the use of if and `.getText().toString()` is not working at all.

Comment: for string equality you must use `.equals()` instead of `==` so change `maintext =="10"` to `maintext.equals("10")`

Comment: As well you need not to convert maintext to String because getText() will always returns string value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: @Madhu `getText()` return `Editable` object, so `.toString()` is need,

Comment: @shayanpourvatan yes i agree but (String) is no need when using getText().toString right

Comment: @Madhu, yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

**==** tests object references, **.equals()** tests the string values.

use `equals`

```
if(maintext.equals("10"))
```

Finally

```
    if(maintext.equals("10"))
    {

        ToneGenerator toneG = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100);
        toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200);


   }
```

> [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly comparing two strings (`maintext =="10"`), change it to `"10".equals(maintext)`